# Why is the value of this uint32_t always 0?

Tags: c++

Setting up a method to calculate ID3 frame sizes, but the variable *frsz* always returns 0. I need to pass this variable back to another method so the program can loop through the ID3 frames.

```
void frameInfo(File track, char frame[4], uint32_t ltwo[4], int32_t frsz) {
 uint8_t buff[4];
 track.seek(10);
 track.read((uint8_t *)frame, 4);

 track.seek(14);
 track.read((uint8_t *)buff,4); 
 ltwo[0] = buff[0];
 ltwo[1] = buff[1];
 ltwo[2] = buff[2];
 ltwo[3] = buff[3];

 ltwo[0] = ltwo[0] * 2097152;
 ltwo[1] = ltwo[1] * 16384;
 ltwo[2] = ltwo[2] * 128;

 frsz = ltwo[0] + ltwo[1] + ltwo[2] + ltwo[3];

 track.rewind();
}
```

Am I missing some sort of initialization for this uint32?

Comment: What do you mean by “I cannot assign a value to the variable”? Of course you can. Do you mean you would like a variable of _the caller_ to be modified?

Comment: I think the question implies that, Edgar.

Comment: let the function return the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void frameInfo(File track, char frame[4], uint32_t ltwo[4], int32_t frsz) {
```

The way you did it, frsz is passed by value (ie. a copy is made, and you have changed the copy, not the original). To make it change outside the function you need to pass it by reference:

```
void frameInfo(File track, char frame[4], uint32_t ltwo[4], int32_t &frsz) {
```

Note the ampersand.

Comment: normal would be to return the value as return of the function. but we don't know the context.

Comment: That was what I was missing. Thanks Nick!